# How can I have a page title different from the name of its menu link?

Tags: routes

I have the following implementation of hook_menu in a custom module:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function employee_list_menu() {
    $items['employee-list'] = array(
        'title' => 'Employee list',
        'page callback' => 'employee_list_render',
        'access arguments' => array('view employee list'),
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );
    return $items;
}
```

I also have a custom menu in which a menu item link is 'Staff' and the path is 'employee-list'. When I click on the 'Staff' link the page opens and the page title is 'Staff', but I want it to be 'Employee list'. How can I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the page title with [drupal_set_title()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_title/7) in your page callback.